# How to create a "Switch Camera" button for an Android App

Tags: java, android

Hello stackoverflow people, as an EE student with minimal knowledge in app development, I have been assigned the task of "fixing" an unfinished app for my research group. My first task is to implement a toggle button which flips the camera from front to back. I have some ideas, but I'm not sure how to implement them with the old app code.

I want to create a togglebutton listener, and use this listener to decide which camera to use. Currently, I am looking at this section of code...

```
public void openCamera() {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    Log.e(TAG, "opening camera");
    try {
        String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[1];
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
        assert map != null;
        //imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
        imageDimension = new Size(1280, 960);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            showToast("Please grant permissions before starting the service.");
        } else {
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My thought process is that I can make a conditional statement inside of the openCamera class which checks if the toggle button is on or off, and then opens the correct camera(on being front camera, off being back camera). Again, I am completely new to app development, so if this is an incorrect solution please inform me.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research, and I've found some of this code online. This is what I found.

Button otherCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OtherCamera);

```
otherCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (inPreview) {
    camera.stopPreview();
}
//NB: if you don't release the current camera before switching, you app will crash
camera.release();

//swap the id of the camera to be used
if(currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
    currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
}
else {
    currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
}
camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);

setCameraDisplayOrientation(CameraActivity.this, currentCameraId, camera);
try {

    camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
camera.startPreview();
}
```

If you want to make the camera image show in the same orientation as the display, you can use this.

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```